# How to force jquery's trigger function to trigger all events in forloop?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am working on a page where I am using js, php, jquery for saving checkbox input field's value in a javascript array, and later I am using that array, but I dont know why when I am removing fields from php foreach loop and manually giving different value to every checkbox **everything works fine** as you can see in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mujahed_akas/wvr5gof7/24/) which is working fine, it is first displaying *hi*, than *hi,bi* and in last *hi,bi,goodby* as expected.

But when I am populating these input field's value using foreach loop of php, it is 1st displaying blank, than *hi* than *hi,bi* and it is not displaying last *hi,bi,goodby* . I dont know where I am getting this error.

my html code;

```
<input type="checkbox" id="selectall"/>Select all<br>
<input id="live_prod_input" type="checkbox" name="live_prod_chk" value="hi" onclick="click_alert(this.value)"/>Check box 1<br>
<input id="live_prod_input" type="checkbox" name="live_prod_chk" value="bi" onclick="click_alert(this.value)"/>Check box 2<br>
<input id="live_prod_input" type="checkbox" name="live_prod_chk" value="goodby" onclick="click_alert(this.value)"/>Check box 3<br>
```

following is my php code for input field.

```
<?php
 foreach ($result as $value) 
 {
 ?>
 <input id="live_prod_input" type="checkbox" name="live_prod_chk" value="<?= $value['p_id'] ?>" onclick="showPause('show_hide_multi_pause')"/>
 <?php
 }
?>
```

following is result array

```
    Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [p_id] => 110
            [left(p_title,30)] => Samsung GALAXY Note II N7100 [
            [left(p_features,30)] => OS : Android , Display : 4.8&q
            [p_status] => 1
            [od_price] => 800
            [od_offer_price] => 750
            [pi_image1] => Samsung-Galaxy-S3-Neo_1_110.jpg
            [o_sqty] => 65
            [o_cond] => New
            [od_htime] => 2 Business days
        )

[1] => Array
    (
        [p_id] => 127
        [left(p_title,30)] => Samsung Galaxy Note Edge SM-N9
        [left(p_features,30)] => this is DeMo FeAtUrE
        [p_status] => 1
        [od_price] => 654
        [od_offer_price] => 
        [pi_image1] => Samsung Galaxy Note Edge SM-N915G_1_127.jpg
        [o_sqty] => 65
        [o_cond] => Old
        [od_htime] => 
    )
)
```

and I am inserting input value as `$value['p_id']`.

Comment: Please post the php  foreach loop

Comment: @PedroLobito please check I have edited the question and added php code and array, though it is not exactly similar to js fiddle or above html code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can not use same **Id** for multiple elements in same page. 
Instead of using **Id** you can use **class** for each checkbox.
For example,
Instead of 
`$('input#live_prod_input').each(function() {})`

use `$('input.live_prod_input').each(function(){})`

in following checkbox

`<input id="live_prod_input" type="checkbox" name="live_prod_chk" value="hi" onclick="click_alert(this.value)"/>Check box 1<br>`

Replace above **Id** with **class.**

Answer (score 0):

I've reproduced your code on my server and it works with a small change:

On the `php` loop try changing

```
onclick="showPause('show_hide_multi_pause')"
```

to

```
onclick="click_alert(this.value)"
```

This is the php loop that works for me:

```
foreach ($result as $value) 
{
$p_id = $value['p_id'];
echo <<< LOB
<input id="live_prod_input" type="checkbox" name="live_prod_chk" value="$p_id" onclick="click_alert(this.value)"/>
LOB;
}
```

---

**COMPLETE HTML CODE:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
 window.click_alert = function(val) //equivalent to function click_alert()
{
    csv_pause = [];
        var chboxs = document.getElementsByName("live_prod_chk");
        for (var i = 0; i < chboxs.length; i++) {
            if (chboxs[i].checked) {
                csv_pause.push(chboxs[i].value);
            }
        }
     alert(csv_pause);
}



     $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#selectall').click(function() {  //on click 
        if(this.checked) { // check select status
            $('input#live_prod_input').each(function() { //loop through each checkbox
//                this.checked = true;  //select all checkboxes with class "checkbox1" 
                $(this).trigger('click');
//                $('input#live_prod_input').trigger('click');
            }

                    );
        }else{
            $('input#live_prod_input').each(function() { //loop through each checkbox
                this.checked = false; //deselect all checkboxes with class "checkbox1"                       
            });         
        }
    });
   }); 
</script>
</head>
<body>


<input id="live_prod_input" type="checkbox" name="live_prod_chk" value="110" onclick="click_alert(this.value)"/>
<input id="live_prod_input" type="checkbox" name="live_prod_chk" value="120" onclick="click_alert(this.value)"/> 
 </body>
</html>
```